# How to overlay an play button on an image using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking to add an overlay play button on an image, so when I click it I would be able to play an video.My question is that every similar questions are need to add a separate overlay play button in the source.

But what if I can't keep a separate image in the server then  is there are anyway I can achieve the same result using javaScript?. If it can then can someone give a sample code for that.

I DON'T WANT TO USE A SEPARATE PLAY IMAGE..so is there any method I can do it?

Comment: Put the original image and a play button image in a relative positioned wrapping element and position the play button absolute. Done (with just CSS, not JS needed).

Comment: No I mean without using a play button image. can it still do?

Comment: You can style a `div` like a play button for example.

Comment: then how can I do it?. can you post a sample code?

Comment: using a tag or button tag is the ones I know for a button..still using div for clickable button is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little CSS snippet including a JSBin example (http://jsbin.com/tarexami/1/edit?html,css,output):

```
.play-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.play-button:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22px;
  top: 10px;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending Christian's answer, you can use CSS Triangles as your Play button, and absolutely positioning them in a relatively positioned container.

Refer:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/